# What is this Scala 'new' syntax

Tags: scala

From the ScalaTest docs:

```
class ExampleSpec extends FlatSpec {

def fixture =
new {
  val builder = new StringBuilder("ScalaTest is ")
  val buffer = new ListBuffer[String]
}
```

...

I don't understand how the new keyword is being used here.  fixture is obviously a function, which declares and returns... what?  It seems to be an object, since it has members (builder & buffer) that can be accessed with . notation.

Is what is being created here an anonymous class that is a subclass of AnyRef?

Comment: If you want to read more about this, look for "structural refinement" or "structural subtyping"

Comment: I wish I'd have said "INSTANCE of an anonymous class" instead of "anonymous class" - the interchanging of 'object' and 'class' being one of my long-time OO pet-peeves. :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yep, it returns instance of anynomous class. It is not hard to check it by yourself in REPL session:

```
scala> def fixture = new { val string = "mr. String" }
fixture: Object{val string: String}
```

Java can do the essentially same thing, believe it or not. The following is valid Java

```
(new Object() {   
  public void sayHello() {
    System.out.println("hello!");   
  }   
}).sayHello();
```

The Java version is just a mildly more verbose syntax and has a type system limitation that makes it mostly useless.
More about it here http://james-iry.blogspot.com/2009/04/java-has-type-inference-and-refinement.html

Comment: @JamesIry, but sadly in java it is harder to use such anonymous instances not-in-place of creation (assuming we're not using any interfaces and classes).

Comment: It’s worth mentioning that all methods called on an object defined like that are called by reflection.

Comment: Good point Jean - but it should be explained why that's important i.e. reflection is expensive.

Comment: om, I actually use that syntax in Java a lot for Map initialization - a very nice pattern.